# Reversing a tag synonym action

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Is it possible to remove the synonym addition of "facebook-fql" to "fql" so that the correct (imo) logical choice of "fql" -> "facebook-fql" can be made?

[image: Reverse action]

*Question count breakdown*

facebook-fql: **1697 questions**
fql: **1,231 questions**

Answer (score 2):

Deleted and created the opposite synonym relationship.